# Removing left sided duplicates from array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, arraylist, nested-loops

I'm trying to find mistakes in my code and i wonder if you could help me. My task is to write a method that would take an array as an input and return this array without left duplicates(last numbers stay). My code doesn't work in case when input is( 1,2,1,2,1,2,3 ) It returns (1, 1, 2, 3) instead of 1,2,3. Here is the code

```
     public static int [] solve(int [] arr){
          boolean check=false;
        ArrayList<Integer> test = new ArrayList<>(); // idk how to compete this task without ArrayList
          for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { // Here i pass my array to ArrayList
             test.add(arr[i]);
             }
             
            while(check==false) {
                for (int i = 0; i < test.size(); i++) {
                   for (int j = i + 1; j < test.size(); j++) { // Somewhere here must be my mistake that i can't find 
                       check=true;
                       if (test.get(i) == test.get(j)) {
                           test.remove(i);
                          check=false;
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
      // i created second array to return array without duplcates. 
           int arr2[];
             arr2=new int[test.size()];
             for(int i=0;i<arr2.length;i++){
                 arr2[i]=test.get(i);
             }
        
        return arr2;
    
       }
     }
```

I tried to complete this task on my own, so i didnt use Google to get help until now. If you know how to improve my code feel free to change everything you want to. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You want to return only unique values ?

Comment: I want to remove all the duplicates before the last one. For example  - 7,7,4,5,7,2,7( input)  and 4,5,2,7( output). As you see last '7' stays

Comment: Well, its nothing but returning unique elements in the given array right? The position of any last duplicate element means after which there are unique elements only. Or do you want to remove only the duplicate elements of the last duplicate and leave other duplicate elements before last duplicate element unchanged. Which one is it ?

Comment: Yes, i think you get it right

Comment: I said 2 options. If you say my 2nd explanation is right then the output you showed is working as expected right. or for my 1st option if you just want unique elements just use HashSet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way will be to

1. Add the numbers of the array in reverse order to a `LinkedHashSet` in order to keep only unique numbers as well as to preserve the last entry of each unique number.
2. Create a `List` out of the `LinkedHashSet`.
3. Reverse the `List` using `Collections#reverse`.

   ```
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.Collections;
   import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
   import java.util.List;
   import java.util.Set;

   public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           Set<Integer> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
           int[] arr = { 7, 7, 4, 5, 7, 2, 7 };

           // Add the numbers of the array in reverse order to a LinkedHashSet in order to remove
           // duplicates as well as to preserve the last entry of each unique number.
           for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
               set.add(arr[i]);
           }

           // Create a List out of the LinkedHashSet
           List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(set);

           // Reverse the List
           Collections.reverse(list);

           // Display the result
           System.out.println(list);
       }
   }
   ```

**Output:**

```
[4, 5, 2, 7]
```

Comment: Java 21 is adding an `addLast` method to `LinkedHashSet`, which allows for a simplified version of this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76462109/1108305

Answer (score 4):

[HashSet](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_hashset.asp) can do this since you cant put duplicate elements to [HashSet](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_hashset.asp), all you need to do is put your array into [HashSet](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_hashset.asp).

```
List<Integer> arr2 = new ArrayList<>(new HashSet<>(arr));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a second list, iterate through your input list and for each element of your input list check if the second list contains it. If it doesn't, add it to the second list. This passes the test case that you mention in your original post:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      List<Integer> test = new ArrayList<>();
      List<Integer> noduplicates = new ArrayList<>();
      test.add(1);
      test.add(2);
      test.add(1);
      test.add(2);
      test.add(1);
      test.add(2);
      test.add(3);
      
      for (Integer i : test) {
          if (!noduplicates.contains(i)) {
              noduplicates.add(i);
          }
      }
      System.out.println(noduplicates);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Java 21, a [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) can be used with its [`addLast(e)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html#addLast(E)) method.

```java
public static int[] solve(int[] arr) {
    SequencedSet<Integer> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    for (int i : arr) {
        set.addLast(i);
    }
    return set.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
}
```

`LinkedHashSet` is a collection class which disallows duplicates (due to being a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html)) while preserving order (due to being a [`SequencedCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html)).  The `addLast` method adds the given item to the end of the set if it isn't already present, or moves it to the end if it is.